# Need some help Identify a Varistor

Tags: identification, varistor

I had a either a surge or a part failure cook a few components on board. The board is rather old from a discontinued product. On the board the only components I've not been able to identify that need to be replace are, from what I can tell, are 2 identical varistor's.

This is the component:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/TRbNR4E.jpg]

This is schematic from what i've been able to tell.
[image]

If anyone is able to help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please inline your images.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 250VAC varistor from an obsolete [AVX series](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/AVX%20PDFs/VE,%20VF%20Type%20(P%20Series).pdf).

If it's a 5mm disk, as it appears to be, you can probably replace it with another of similar size and voltage rating. MOVs wear out from absorbing surges, so this is not an uncommon occurrence.